# Forwarding/redirecting handler

Tags: php, yii

Let's say I have a handler `actionFoo()` and `actionBar()`.

Can I "redirect" from `/foo` to `/bar`, without actually doing a `30x` HTTP return, but just triggering the `Bar` code from the `Foo` code path?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand well what you want it's execute the code from `Bar` action but without doing a redirection.

Then Manquer answer won't solve your problem, but there is a method in `CController` letting you do it: `forward()`

> Processes the request using another controller action. This is like redirect, but the user browser's URL remains unchanged. In most cases, you should call redirect instead of this method.

[Source](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CController#forward-detail)

Comment: This is of course correct if you really want to call only the code, however the OP should know that this is never a good idea, unless he knows exactly why he needs to do this.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can with something like this

```
function actionFoo(){
    $this->redirect(array('bar'));
}
```

See [Redirect](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CController#redirect-detail) documentation for more details